# Is it possible for a structure field to contain a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm working on an assignment where I have to read a tab delimited text file and my output has to be a matlab structure.

The contents of the file look like this (It is a bit messy but you get the picture). The actual file contains 500 genes (the rows starting at Analyte 1) and 204 samples (the columns starting at A2)

```
#1.2                                    
500 204                             
Name        Desc        A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2  G2  H2
Analyte 1   Analyte 1   978 903 1060    786 736 649 657 733.5
Analyte 2   Analyte 2   995 921 995.5   840 864.5   757 739 852
Analyte 3   Analyte 3   1445.5  1556.5  1579    1147.5  1249    1069.5  1048    1235
Analyte 4   Analyte 4   1550    1371    1449    1127    1196    1337    1167    1359
Analyte 5   Analyte 5   2074    1776    1960    1653    1544    1464    1338    1706
Analyte 6   Analyte 6   2667    2416.5  2601    2257    2258    2144    2173.5  2348
Analyte 7   Analyte 7   3381.5  3013.5  3353    3099.5  2763    2692    2774    2995
```

My code is as follows:

```
fid = fopen('gene_expr_500x204.gct', 'r');%Open the given file

% Skip the first line and determine the number or rows and number of samples
dims = textscan(fid, '%d', 2, 'HeaderLines', 1);
ncols = dims{1}(2);

% Now read the variable names
varnames = textscan(fid, '%s', 2 + ncols);
varnames = varnames{1};

% Now create the format spec for your data (2 strings and the rest floats)
spec = ['%s%s', repmat('%f', [1 ncols])];

% Read in all of the data using this custom format specifier. The delimiter     will be a tab
data = textscan(fid, spec, 'Delimiter', '\t');

% Place the data into a struct where the variable names are the fieldnames
ge = data{3:ncols+2}
S = struct('gn', data{1}, 'gd', data{2}, 'sid', {varnames});
```

The part about ge is my current attempt but its not really working. Any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `struct` field can hold *any* datatype including a multi-dimensional array or matrix.

Your issue is that `data{3:ncols+2}` creates a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Since you only have one output on the left side of the assignment, `ge` will only hold the *last* column's value. You need to use `cat` to concatenate all of the columns into a big matrix.

```
ge = cat(2, data{3:end});

% Or you can do this implicitly with []
% ge = [data{3:end}];
```

Then you can pass this value to the `struct` constructor

```
S = struct('gn', data(1), 'gd', data(2), 'sid', {varnames}, 'ge', ge);
```

Comment: Thank you again Suever! It worked perfectly. Follow up question, am I now able to use these fields to construct plots/graphs?

Comment: Yes you can access any field using dot-notation: `plot(S.ge(:,1))` etc.